# Find documents by child value?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to find all document IDs with `name: "Nick"`, so I can update the `score`.

---

I have the following `Firestore Database` structure:

```json
{
  "c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b": {
    title: "Tiger",
    user: {
      name: "Chris",
      score: 1
    }
  },
  "c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c": {
    title: "Lion",
    user: {
      name: "Nick",
      score: 2
    }
  }
}
```

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) I see that I can find documents using `where` like this:

```js
const dbQuery = query(collection(dbFirestore, "posts"), where("title", "==", "Tiger"));

const dbSnapshot = await getDocs(dbQuery);

dbSnapshot.forEach((result) => {
  console.log(result.id, " => ", result.data());
});
```

But I don't see anything about how to search by a child element (`user.name`)?

Comment: Are you using Firestore or the Realtime Database?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I'm using the latest version of Firestore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore is a NoSQL database which inherits how you query on any other NoSQL database. To specify a query condition on fields in an embedded/nested document, use dot notation `"field.nestedField"`. When querying using dot notation, the field and nested field must be inside quotation marks.

You could get all the documents from nested objects by using this sample query:

```
const dbQuery = query(collection(db, "posts"), where("user.name", "==", "Nick"));

const dbSnapshot = await getDocs(dbQuery);

dbSnapshot.forEach((result) => {
  console.log(result.id, " => ", result.data());
});
```

Comment: `where("user.name", "==", "Nick")` is way simplier than I thought it would be, lol! Thank you so much for your help!